SD card via SPI: any way of getting it out of stuck state after aborted SPI operation(s) without power cycling it?
using ESP32 and its IDF platform libraries to access SD card via SPI, we have a situation where e.g. panic reboot of ESP32 leaves the SD card 'stuck' such that it cannot be mounted any more after reboot - only powercycling the entire system gets it out of this state.
Since it is likely that ongoing SPI transaction aborted (read or write, it would be totally random) when ESP32 rebooted (and left SD card in some state still waiting for finishing transaction and/or confused), after having read and not found much on this scenario:
Would there be any general way of e.g. clocking it into some idle state, essentially getting it back to some state where it could be mounted again via the platform's respective APIs? Just trying to mount it does not lead anywhere, so repeated attempts failing make at least me assume that card is in a state that somehow needs to be reset / cleaned up.
As the card is not directly accessible and power cycling everything is the least desirable (but currently only working 'solution'), some firmware solution would be idea... However, all initialisation sequences for physical layer on SD card start with the clean initial states instead of some jammed-up SPI transaction.
Maybe it is not even possible... but any thoughts would be hugely appreciated.

So controlling card power in software to make it reboot when ESP32 rebooted is not possible? If it does not recover then the initialization sequence does not take into account that card was already initialized into use. And IIRC, when the card is put into SPI mode, the card will never go out of SPI mode unless powered down. So the init sequence needs to deal with cards that were already initialized into SPI mode and just reset them. So this isn't about mounting.

Indeed. The (for us) opaque sequence of mounting fails overall - presumably at early stages when it assumes it has to start from scratch with the SD card. Not sure whether the card can be so stuck because some transaction vanished at a random point that it would not be resetable any more - if this can happen, then I guess only power cycling will help. Otherwise the puzzle is how reset sequence would differ for such an 'abandoned' card compared to the usual one - then the practicality is to make it happen via the platform but that's another detail

Digging deeper, with some verbose logs from their lib, it seems to be (when it fails) a CRC error to CMD 52 when it, as first step, wants to reset the card.  So if one somehow managed to "get in there" and somehow (??) clock out junk or clear out that bad state... then the init and mounting sequence might work perhaps. But what could such extra init sequence be... just repeating the command a number of times, and hope that some dealignment / bad state goes? Or needs some series of e.g. dummy clocking or...

can you power the card though a gpio? that makes it trivial to reset...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Unfortunately, current and foreseeable HW doesn't give us the card power control :(
In the library I found that they issue CMD52 as first command before the setup sequence. However, when restarting just the microcontroller, the card is already set up and has CRC check turned on. Their code aborts entire setup on this CRC error that is actually expected in such cases. Also the physical layer standard says that in SPI mode must not use CRC except for CMD0 and CMD8. So just by allowing CRC error in this first IOreset step, it then mounts it successfully. So this actually might be enough.
